# how to read cassandra database query results to UI in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra, pug

I have a js function like

```
router.get('/cassandra', function (req, res)
{
client.connect(function(err){
    });

client.execute('SELECT * FROM monica.emp;', function (err, result) {
 var user = result.rows[0];

 console.log("here is the user", result);
}
res.render('cassandra',{"cassandra":result});
});
});
```

What i am doing is getting the first row and then accessing the objects of that row.

but the actual 'result' output is a set of rows(collection) 
like 
[image]

How do i pass this set to jade and display this on a UI page??

Right now if I am doing it like below I am getting undefined error. 
extends layout

```
block content
    p Cassandra  



    for item in cassandra
        li
            a= ' '+ ' '+ item.empid
```

P.S I do not want to access each row using result.rows[0] result.rows[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7rt4.gif) result.rows[2]etc..
my select * statement just gives me the set of entries present. I want to be able to access this set to print it on User Interface

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood you have result with structure like this,

```
result => {meta: {}, rows: [{}, {}]}
```

If yes, you can get rows as shown below

```
 // res.render('cassandra',{cassandra: result});

  ul
    each el in cassandra.rows
      li
        a= el.empid
```

if not, give an example of your result in reduced form.